# Что быстрее работает вставка сток в html или вставка DOM элементов при помощи js

Tags: javascript

Изучаю javascript и появился вопрос, возможно он покажется глупым, но все мы когда-то были любознательными новичками.
Вопрос заключается в следующем: Имеется 15 строк html кода которые нужно вставить в страницу несколько раз.
Что лучше использовать простую вставку html строк через insertAdjacentHTML или создавать для этой цели DOM элементы и вставлять их?
Вставляем элементы массива при переборе переборе через forEach

Comment: почему бы не попробовать и не засечь?

Comment: щас вообще все сайты активно и большом кол-ве используют js и это очень сильно замедляет работу сайтов ..вся эта эмуляция сети 2G или 3G лажа полная ...вот только сейчас  я приехал от туда где есть только 3G с жирным минусом и не один сайт не работает с одного клика ...либо вообще не открываются `settimeout error` либо тупо появляется Dino ..лучше php ни чего нету

Comment: Зависит от браузера. Выберите браузер, для которого  пишите и там протестируйте.